# Remove a specific NPM Package from build/generate but provide it during development [nuxt/vue/webpack]

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack, nuxt.js

I am trying to remove the Tailwindcss package from a Nuxt Project during the build genereate.

My plan is to provide all tailwindcss classes during development but exclude the tailwindcss module during generate\build.

Is there a way to include NPM Packages during development but remove or exclude them for the build\generate process in nuxt or any other webpack project?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove tailwind during generate"? What does it mean for you? You'll need the package to actually have CSS on your production built app. Are you sure you want to have it only during development?

Comment: I want to generate the purged css in a pregenerate script i wrote. It basically does the same thing as the nuxt tailwind package but with the pregenerate script, I can compile 2 seperate style.css from 2 seperate tailwind.configs

Answer (score 0):

You can install using --save-dev:

`npm install tailwindcss --save-dev`

It will save in dev environment.

Comment: `npm i -D tailwindcss` is enough nowadays.

Comment: @kissu Thank you, It is helpful to me, when i install next time